# What are the advantages of combining a type selector with an id selector? e.g. div#some_id

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is extremely simple but I am wondering why people write this?

```
div#some_id
```

You can only have one ID of that name "some_id" on a webpage. So why be specific with it? Is it for readability purposes?

Comment: its a wrong way its makes CSS rendering slow, because rendering engines read CSS from right to left so, first it search for id than for that tag. But as id are unique you should just write the id.

Comment: The id may be unique, but the context (it being a `div` on one page and maybe an `ul` on another) may be not.

Comment: @SVS: Right to left has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @BoltClock But its making rendring slow as there is no use of using the tag if a id is assigned to it.

Comment: Yeah. I said right-to-left has nothing to do with it. I didn't say it wasn't making it slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of possible reasons:

- It is a more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) selector
- It tells people reading the stylesheet that the selector is aiming at a div element
- The same id could be applied to different element types on different pages that use the same stylesheet (this usually causes more confusion then benefits though, so I wouldn't advise that approach).

Comment: I like your answer but its not valid to add the same ID "some_id" to a div and span.

Comment: @W3Geek: Across different pages, read carefully (I almost tripped myself :)

Comment: Ah okay, I see that makes way more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, but this would mean a **div** with an ID of `some_id`. (More correctly, an element with an ID of `some_id`, which is also a `div`).

This grants a higher specificity value, but you're right. It's usually worthless with IDs, more useful with class names.

For example:

```
div.large { width: 500px; /* 500px is a large div */ }
input.large { width: 100px; /* 100px is a large input */ }
```

Same class name, different results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is done is mainly for readability in the stylesheet.

As you can only have 1 id on a page it makes sense that you would not need to specify which type of element it is.