# CSS declaration - element type and ID or just ID?

Tags: html, css, class

How should I use CSS declaration?

This way:

```
div#main_content {
    width: 900px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or this way:

```
#main_content {
    width: 900px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In sublime text 2, sublime linter package suggested me to use without the `div` - only #main_content, but on some tutorial I saw that it is better to use div#main_content as it is easier to parse.

What do you suggest I should use? (I think result will be the same in this case for the classes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of combining a type selector with an id selector? e.g. div#some_id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428210/what-are-the-advantages-of-combining-a-type-selector-with-an-id-selector-e-g-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to just use the id. There should only be one element on the page with a given id, so the element type is redundant.

Another reason to miss off the element type is that if you decide to change your HTML (maybe changing the `<div>` to something more semantic like a `<p>` or `<section>`) the CSS selector will still match.

Answer (score 2):

The only scenario where including the element type with the ID is truly beneficial (that I can think of) is if you are going to apply the same ID to different element types on different pages and want to style them differently.

For example, if on your home page, you create `<header id="main">` and on other pages you have `<section id="main">`, you would definitely want to use `header#main` and `section#main` respectively to style the two elements.

If your ID is going to be applied to the same element type across all pages, then the element selector in your CSS would only serve to increase legibility of your CSS, should you wish to know what type of element you're styling.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't that much difference, ID's are the fastest so use them and you will fine, using div#id just says only affect the id if it is inside a div (you may want this functionality at some point, though probably with a class, not an id)