# Is it better to be specific when selecting IDs in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say you have a `div` element with an id of `main`.

Since there can only be one element with a particular id, referencing it in CSS like `div#main` is the equivalent of referencing it with `#main`.

So, what's generally better practice, `div#main`, or `#main`?

As a side note, you are absolutely positive that the element you are trying to reference is a `div`, so which selector should you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798029/css-declaration-element-type-and-id-or-just-id

Comment: There might be a situation in which the page's code changes, e.g. AJAX request, and you only want a style applied if the ID exists on a certain element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to specify anything beyond the id itself is working against the purpose of an id. If used as intended, there should only ever be a single element with any given id, so specifying any further shouldn't be needed. If the id could or should exist in multiple places it is likely a class not an id